# C++ .lib file to mex

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, lib

I was wondering if anyone has experience creating mex files from C++ .lib files. I am given a .lib and its corresponding .h file and need to make the .lib callable from Matlab.

Side note: Because the c++ file is a .lib, I can not see the implementation for the .lib file but I am capable of making the calls defined in its .h.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Mex command as linker. You compile your everything into object files with whatever compiler you prefer, then use Mex command to link them into Mex executable.

Comment: Cut mex out of the equation and build a regular program from the command line to make sure you know what switches you need to pass to the compiler. Then it may be as simple as calling mex with the same switches.  Works with g++ at least.

Answer (score 1):

Your .lib most likely don't support the Matlab format so you have to make wrapper functions. Here is a small example (where addMat() could be a function from your .lib)

```
#include "mex.h"
//#include "Your_lib.h"

// Your local C++ function
void addMat( double *in1, double *in2, double *out, int R, int C)
{
    for (int n=0; n<R*C; n++) 
    {
       out[n] = in1[n]+in2[n];
    }
}

// The Matlab wrapper 
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *inMat1,*inMat2,*outMat;
    mwSize R,C; 

    // Pointer to an mxArray of type double
    inMat1 = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    inMat2 = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

    // Get size (assume both are the same as 1st arg)
    R = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    C = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

    // Create an real output mxArray of size [R,C]
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(R,C,mxREAL);
    outMat  = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);     

    // Call your own function or lib
    addMat(inMat1,inMat2,outMat,R,C);
}
```

If your wrapper file is called `addMat.cpp` then you may compile it as

```
mex addMat.cpp
```

and it will generate a mex file, run it in Matlab:

```
A=addMat([1 2 3;1 1 1],[10 11 12; 2 2 2])

A =

    11    13    15
     3     3     3
```

The build command with an external lib should be something like

```
mex -I<include dir> -L<lib dir> -l<your lib>.lib addMat.cpp
```

Comment: So just to be clear, I would need to reference calls in the lib from a separate c++ class? Then by compiling this separate .cpp file using the "mex ___.cpp" command I will be able to access these functions within Matlab? (assuming they're in the same directory) Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You only need to make wrappers for the functions you call directly from Matlab. The generated .mexw64 files can be located in any directory, as long as they are included in the Matlab path ( see addpath() )